# Cannot create a database schema with PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm unable to create a MySQL database schema and assign user privileges via PDO, I can't find anything wrong with my code:

```
    $db = $this->pdo->prepare( 'CREATE SCHEMA :dbName;
                            GRANT ALL ON :dbName.* TO :dbUser@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY :dbPassword' );
    $db->bindParam( ':dbName', $dbName, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $db->bindParam( ':dbUser', $dbUser, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $db->bindParam( ':dbPassword', $dbPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $db->execute();
    var_export($db->errorInfo());
```

returns:
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'test\'; GRANT ALL ON \'test\'.* TO \'test\' at line 1'

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 The query I'm using is valid and tested in console.

Comment: If multiple queries work you are probably running with emulated prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Parameters (such as `:dbName`) take scalar inputs such as strings and numbers.  You can't use them for column names or table names; those must be entered into the query explicitly.  That is, `CREATE SCHEMA 'test'` will fail, but `CREATE SCHEMA test` is what you need.
- PDO cannot run more than one query in a single statement (on purpose).  Split this into separate queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really wanted to avoid exec-like queries.
PDO actually does accept multiple queries in a single prepare statement, tested.